# Blazor Authentication - Http calls does work for anonymous

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, forms-authentication, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have been playing with blazor with .net 5.0. I am stuck with a simple but annoying issue: I am trying to load data from API but every call to the Server blazor expects the user to be signed in.

I understood if we took out [Authorize] tag from the API controller and don't have `@attribute [Authorize]` in the razor page, and that would be it. But I am struggling to understand why my API call still expects AccessToken in `protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()` the error messages don't say much around why.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AccessTokenNotAvailableException: ''
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.AuthorizationMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I haven't touched the App. cs file of the web assembly..

Can anyone help please.

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <h4>Authentication in progress...</h4>
                </Authorizing>                
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Comment: Could you please upload your app to github...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured the solution ... should have looked at it first.

it was actually the **App.CS** fill in the Client Project. Http endpoint is initiated there, and by default the code-gen adds BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler to the httpclient.

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("private", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
       .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
```

how I solved it was using named clients one for **Private** and one for **Public** like so

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("private", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("public", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
```

and in pages inject IHttpClientFactory

```
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory
```

and create a named client from the factory.

```
var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("public");
```

This worked.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because you have `CascadingAuthenticationState` encapsulating both `Found`context and `NotFound` since what it does is to pass authorization information down to other components. So, wrapping it around all your components prevents access to unauthorized users. Try this instead

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                }
            </NotAuthorized>
            <Authorizing>
                <h4>Authentication in progress...</h4>
            </Authorizing>                
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Comment: I tried this and it made no differentce at all...